# Error No Session found for current thread when trying to save into two database simultaneously

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Hi i'm trying to save into two database simultaneously but I always get an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

here's my code :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly=false)
public void save(ArsenalPlayer domain1, ArsenalPlayer2 domain2)
        throws Exception {

    dao1.save(domain1);
    dao2.save(domain2);

}
```

- dao1 uses a sessionFactory attached to datasource1
- dao2 uses a sessionFactory attached to datasource2

and here's my configuration

**DataSource**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/arsenal" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="ahmids" />
</bean>
```

**SessionFactory**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.gongfu4.bean.ArsenalPlayer</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**DataSource2**

```
<bean id="dataSource2" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/arsenal2" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="ahmids" />
</bean>
```

**SessionFactory2**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory2"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> --> 
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.gongfu4.bean.ArsenalPlayer2</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**applicationContext**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gongfu4" />

<context:annotation-config />

<import resource="dataSource.xml" />
<import resource="dataSource2.xml" />
<import resource="hibernate.xml" />
<import resource="hibernate2.xml" />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="myTx"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2" />
</bean>
```

and here are my dao classes :

**DAO1**

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void save(ArsenalPlayer domain) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(domain);
}
```

**DAO2**

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory2;

public void save(ArsenalPlayer2 domain) {
    sessionFactory2.getCurrentSession().merge(domain);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: where is the line that causes the exception

Comment: try using openSession() instead of currentSession()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use those two transaction managers like that. You have two data sources, two transaction managers and, from your code, I understand that you want the two save operations to be performed in the same transaction. The question is "a transaction from which transaction manager?".

The way you have the code and the configuration, Spring will use the "default" transaction manager because `<tx:annotation-driven/>` by default will search for a transaction manager bean with the id "transactionManager" and the bean with this id is the one for data source `dataSource`. But your code is not working and this is the expected behavior. Spring will open a Hibernate session using `sessionFactory` and the `dao1.save(domain1);` call will succeed because this is the correct Hibernate session for the correct dataSource. But when the `dao2.save(domain2);` method is called you will have the same session from `dao1` call but be used for a db operation for the second database.

As I see it you have two options:

1. Use a JTA transaction manager to coordinate the two datasources. With a JTA the two save operations will be atomic. If one fails, then both are rolled back.
2. Perform the two `save(domain)` operations in two different transactions properly configuring the `@Transactional` annotation to use the correct transaction manager. In this case, the two save operations will not be atomic. If one save fails then only that one will be rolled-back. See below an exempt taken from the Spring reference documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional):

```
    public class TransactionalService {

    @Transactional("order")
    public void setSomething(String name) { ... }

    @Transactional("account")
    public void doSomething() { ... }
    }
```

```
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        ...
        <qualifier value="order"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        ...
        <qualifier value="account"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: yes, i want to save to both database in one transaction method, so if one operation fails to save, both database will be rolled back, dao1 save operation doesnt have any problem, but when it goes to dao2, i always get an "No Session found for current thread" error. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Then you need to go with option #1 - using a JTA transaction manager. Take a look at [this](http://blog.9mmedia.com/?p=489) blog post that uses Atomikos (a JTA provider) to coordinate two separate data sources. Please, note that you need to change pretty much in your configuration: starting from the datasources definitions (which need to be XA) and then changing the session factories and in the end defining the Atomikos configuration.

Comment: so i have to use JTA transaction to handle multiple databases. thanks for your information and given the link. i will accept your answers. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your current configuration doesn't support global transactions (XA) and therefore you can't span one Transaction on two different databases.

For this reason you need two Hiberante transaction managers, one for each session factory. Then you need to instruct the transactional service which transaction manager should be used.

So instead of:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly=false)
public void save(ArsenalPlayer domain1, ArsenalPlayer2 domain2)
    throws Exception {
    dao1.save(domain1);
    dao2.save(domain2);
}
```

you should have:

```
<bean id="txManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2" />
</bean>

@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly=false, value="txManager1")
public void save(ArsenalPlayer domain1)
    throws Exception {
    dao1.save(domain1);
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly=false, value="txManager2")
public void save(ArsenalPlayer domain2)
    throws Exception {
    dao2.save(domain2);
}
```

Comment: i did have two transaction manager one with id = "transactionManager" and other with id = "myTx" and each injected with difference sessionFactory, from your answer it seems if one transaction fails, it will rolled back the fails one, not both database, btw sorry for my bad english

Comment: Indeed that's what it happens if you don't use JTA. JTA enables global transactions to span over multiple data sources. But you'll need a JTA transaction manager like the one a JEE app server provides you or a stand-alone one, like Bitronix, Atomikos.